# How can I publish an R function using a Plumber API? I want to call the function and publish it in the form of an HTTP response

Tags: r, plumber

I've been successful in publishing a code file using Plumber, but've been unsuccessful in all my attempts to call a function and publish it in the form of an HTTP response.

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb(predictTest.R)
r$run
```

Shown above is the code I've been using to publish a single code file.

When I use the same syntax for a function like:

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb(predictTest("India","Australia"))
r$run
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

How can I call a function and publish it as a HTTP response?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm doing this project as part of my internship at a software company and I'm not allowed to disclose the source as yet.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation on the `plumb` function (type `?plumb` in R or view it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plumber/versions/0.4.6/topics/plumb)). You'll see that it expects

```
plumb(file, dir = ".")
```

I.e., the first argument is the *filename* of a R script file. That's why the first code example works and the second does't; you cannot provide `plumb` with the output from a function (unless that output returns a filename of an R file).

If you only want to expose a single function to plumber, isolate it in a file and use that. If you meant something else, ask a new question and provide more examples. And when you cannot disclose any of your data or source, try making a minimal working example with base R stuff that isn't proprietary to your company.

Finally, read the documentation at https://www.rplumber.io/docs/. You might be interested in chapter 8 and defining end-points.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please consider marking it as the correct answer and/or giving it an upvote.